# How to create a backdrop component under a Flatlist?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to invoke an action/event if a user pressed under a `<FlatList />` component. Here's what I have so far:

```
. . .
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
    <View style={{ flex: 300, width: Dimensions.get('screen').width, height: Dimensions.get('screen').height }}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        style={{
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'white',
          width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
          height: Dimensions.get('screen').height,
        }}
        onPress={() => console.log('clicked')}
      >
        <Text>Backdrop button</Text>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  </View>
);
. . .
```

And this renders the follow:
[image: img]

It just seems too hacky for me, how can I get this to work better? I don't want to keep adding onto the `flex` value (in the code snippet, it is `flex: 300`) and I feel like I don't need `Dimensions`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this:

```
. . .
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
        <View style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignSelf: 'stretch',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
        }}
      >
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          style={{
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'white',
            alignSelf: 'stretch',
            width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
            height: '100%',
          }}
          onPress={() => console.log('clicked!')}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Click me</Text>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    </View>
)
. . .
```

Neither sure if it's the best approach or if it will bring me problems in the future, but it seems to work for now. Looks like this:

[image]